# MySQL MATCH AGAINST on Two Tables Not Sorting by Relevance

Tags: mysql, match, match-against, against

I have a stored procedure using `MATCH AGAINST` that was originally returning data sorted by relevance, which is what I wanted. However, when I added a `LEFT JOIN` and a second `MATCH AGAINST`, it is now returning data from both, but no longer sorting by relevance. It is now automatically sorting by the ID.

**Returning from one table sorted by relevance**:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT
        dictionary.id,
        dictionary.`term`,
        dictionary.`definition`
    FROM itDictionary dictionary
    WHERE MATCH(dictionary.term, dictionary.definition)
    AGAINST(_query IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
END
```

**Returning from two tables but somehow sorting by ID**:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT
        dictionary.id,
        dictionary.`term`,
        dictionary.`definition`,
        links.id,
        links.`name`,
        links.`url`
    FROM itDictionary dictionary
        LEFT JOIN itRelatedLinks links ON links.term_id = dictionary.id
    WHERE MATCH(dictionary.term, dictionary.definition)
    AGAINST(_query IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
        OR MATCH(links.name)
    AGAINST(_query IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
END
```

Am I close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT
    dictionary.id,
    dictionary.`term`,
    dictionary.`definition`,
    links.id,
    links.`name`,
    links.`url`
FROM itDictionary dictionary
    LEFT JOIN itRelatedLinks links ON links.term_id = dictionary.id
WHERE MATCH(dictionary.term, dictionary.definition)
AGAINST(_query IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    OR MATCH(links.name)
AGAINST(_query IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH(dictionary.term, dictionary.definition)
AGAINST(_query IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    + MATCH(links.name)
AGAINST(_query IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

It would add the score of both and have so a combined score to sort by

Of xourse you can add a factor to each score to  prioritise one

Comment: Hey @nbk thanks! I feel like this got me there. I just needed to do a final sort in descending order to have the highest number of search string count at the top of the list. I don't know if this is possible, but say I search for two words "account network". It's currently ordering all rows matching "account" and listing all of those before ordering all rows matching "network", then at the end it's adding any rows with a link matching "account" or "network". Top of the results is id 42, with "account" 4 times between term and def, tapers down from there, then moves onto "network" for example